# Downvoting for no stated reason is abusive

Tags: discussion, comment, voting, down-votes

When I post a short simple answer to a posted question and someone downvotes it, they should be able to explain their objections if I so request.  During the months I've been here, I don't recall that any such requests from me have been ignored until it happened twice within the past week.  Could there at least be some officially promulgated norm about politeness and about respect for the fact that we are here for a common purpose, that says something about this?

Comment: Related post: [1479](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/).

Comment: You can ask for an explanation of the downvote, but no one should be feel obligated to give you any. No one has any obligation to explain upvotes, either!

Comment: I don't think I've cast any votes that I would or could not explain if asked.  Nor should anyone else.

Comment: @Michael: On what grounds do you assert categorically that **your** behaviour should be the model which everyone else should emulate? Certainly, if *you* don't like it, then it would be hypocritical for you to do it to others; but the fact that *you* do not do so does not mean that nobody else "should". So, kindly, get off that high horse.

Comment: @Arturo: instead of in-your-face boldface and attribution of behaviors that may or may not be there (riding a "high horse") it would be more productive to deal with the question, not the poster.

Comment: @Arturo I did not say that my behavior should be a model that others should emulate.

Comment: I downvote this post because I disagree with it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: "I don't think I've cast any votes that I would or could not explain if asked. *Nor should anyone else*." If that's not an indication that you believe that everyone should behave in the way that you behave, then I don't know what is.

Comment: @zyx: "In-your-face boldface" would be attributing behavior that may or may not be there. It's called "emphasis" where I come from. In  meta, I express my opinion, which is, as I understand it, what is supposed to happen. So, in my opinion, you might also want to dismount.

Comment: @Jonas: I upvoted your comment because I like the spirit in which (I thought) it was written!

Comment: @Arturo If you write "The sum of the square is not generally equal to the square of the sum", does that imply that if _you_ believe that then others should too, and that generally others should believe whatever you believe?

Comment: @Michael: I see; so your objection was not to the function, but to the implied *domain* of the function: you believe that, in terms of casting negative votes, everyone should behave the way you do. You objected to the wording which you read as refering to *all* your actions, not just that one. Well, the question stands: why is it that your behavior, *in this particular issue*, is to be the model to which everyone should adhere?

Comment: @Arturo, that seems to be slightly disingenious. If I believe strongly that everyone in situation X should do Y, and therefore I do Y myself when I'm in situation X, then you could express that as "everyone in situation X should do what I do". However, phrasing it that way could conflate cause and effect. It's not that everybody should do it _because_ I do it; on the contrary I do it because I think everybody should. (I agree, though, that mere fact that I follow my own rule is not a particularly relevant fact in a discussion about whether the rule is reasonable).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I was going to answer your comment, but Henning Makholm's has said what needed to be said.  I'm surprised this point wasn't obvious to you.

Comment: @Michael: The discussion, as Henning notes in parenthesis, is *whether* the behavior you believe should be followed is something that others agree should be followed. By merely asserting that you follow your own rule, you are simply saying "I am not a hypocrite". You are not, however, justifying the validity, reasonableness, or reason-why-everyone-should-follow the rule. I'm surprised this point wasn't obvious to you. I asked *why*; simply saying "I do it" is not a reason why; simply implying "I believe strongly everyone should do it" does not say *why* either.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: But that's precisely the point of asking *why*. Not merely because "I believe strongly in it", and not merely because "Look! I am not a hypocrite!".

Comment: @Arturo: none of that explains (and it seems inconsistent with) your "get of the high horse" comment.  Exactly which comments of MH indicate horsemanship, and how?

Comment: @zyx: The entire attitude, like yours, seems to me to be of moralism and telling the rest of the people what they ought to do, based on nothing except personal belief. "I do it; everyone should do it, period." Couched in nice words sometimes, like "feedback", of course, and claims of utter unconcern. That said, don't expect further replies from me.

Comment: @Arturo:if you think that the words "it would be more productive to deal with the question, not the poster" are a form (or attitude) of moralism and control, maybe a meta thread is in order; it's likely that the quoted words represent an *overwhelming consensus* about the use of the meta and the main site.  And while you may not owe any replies to me, your commandment to MH to "get off the high horse" does incur some obligation (to him, and to the others who contested your characterization) to explain *exactly what* that he did say, does amount to such horsemanship, and how.

Comment: @zyx: I think your comments at me following that post, not just here but as a whole, exhibit a pattern of moralising at me as a whole; and that you then self-servingly called them "feedback". (You might also want to point out how "telling people what they *ought* to do" is equivalent to "control"; telling people what you/I/we think they ought to do is not the same thing as controlling people). And I did say exactly what he said that raised that response, and why: "I do this, everyone else should also do this", with the only justification given for the consequent being the antecedent.

Comment: @Arturo I didn't explain why that rule should be followed because I thought it would be obvious.  If you donwvote a question or an answer without stating your objections, then the poster fails to find out that something in it was objectionable---let alone specifically what it is.  The information is useless.

Comment: @Arturo: at no point was any criticism of your obnoxious commentary packaged as mere "feedback". It was pointed (as well as specific, accurate, documented and usable) criticism, straightforwardly presented as such. As I wrote at the time, it would be very good for this site if you heeded the criticism *as* feedback, instead of debating it or attacking the messenger. As for "telling people what they ought to do", I have not done that; but you do routinely use the imperative (as in your command to the OP, visible above) and the permissive ("you can [do X]", "you are free to [do Y]").

Comment: zyx: Downvoting anonymously and without any specified reason can also be used for a type of "control". To try and make people you dislike shut up or go away. That kind of behaviour undermines substance and merit and ultimately risks scaring skilled people away. 

My experience is that people who like such consequences do it because they increase their own chance to look good in comparison...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I don't agree at all. Upvotes and downvotes are completely different. One is constructive and the other is destructive. They are completely different (obviously not symmetric). Its very simple in my opinion, if you have a reason to down vote, then you should be transparent to why you did it, otherwise, how do we know its a sincere down vote? If its an genuine down vote, then the down voter should have nothing to hide.

Comment: Downvotes are not destructive. And how do I know that your upvotes are sincere, or that you even understand what you are upvoting? I demand you explain your upvotes!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : Downvotes mean the poster ought to do something differently.  But _what that is_ is often unknown.  Just recently I posted an answer that got three down-votes and five up-votes.  What those three people objected to I simply don't know. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: No. Downvotes mean all sort of different things (this answer did not help me, I did not understand this, Your notation sucks, Your answer is cut&paste from someone else's, You answered last, I do not like you, This is wrong, and many nore things)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : That's just it.  You can't know which of those many things it means if the voter doesn't explain it.  They always mean the poster should have done something differently, but there's no way to know what.

Comment: There is a similar numbr of different meanings of upvotes.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : But an up-vote does not mean the poster should do something differently.  A down-vote does, but it doesn't tell the poster what should be done differently.

Comment: Honestly I do not see the point in reviving this discussion, which was settled an age ago and regarding which nothing has changed.

Answer (score 36):

No, it is not *abusive* to downvote for no stated reason.

Comment: I want to add that I had a look at the downvoted answers from the OP and the pattern is: The downvotes are explained and the OP either does not respond or responds with "Yes, it is wrong", but lets the wrong answer stand.

Comment: Be explicit.  In which of the five cases did that happen?  Look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67171/calculating-the-modular-multiplicative-inverse-without-all-those-strange-looking/67190#67190 Show me one where the downvotes are explains or where I said "Yes it is wrong."  Show me one where the answer I wrote was wrong.  Show me a case where I let a wrong answer stand.

Comment: Here is the most recent one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77542/how-do-i-apply-limit-here/77549#77549  Did anyone say it's wrong?  Is it wrong?  Did I say "Yes it is wrong" and let it stand?  I see no reason to alter the answer.  I think it's a good answer.

Comment: Here's another: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77047/is-the-function-really-analytic-at-infty/77048#77048  Did someone explain the downvote?  (Rhetorical question.  They didn't do so in the other cases I mention above either.)  Is it wrong?  Did I say "Yes it is wrong" and let it stand?  (Rhetorical question; I did not.)  Again, I think it's a good answer.  Phira, why are you reporting that you've found cases in which a downvote is explained?  Why are you reporting that I've acknowledged errors and let them stand, when that has not happened?

Comment: Here's another: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77863/use-of-one-word-in-the-explanation-of-fraction-0-0/77872#77872  In _this_ case, someone did say something slightly critical of the answer, and I responded?  Is my answer wrong?  Did I say "Yes, it is wrong" and let it stand?  How do you find a "pattern" that has not occurred in any particular instance?

Comment: Phira, you lie.  You are dishonest.

Comment: I have flagged this answer for moderator attention because the comment immediately following it is dishonest.

Comment: @Michael: Since you asked: How about [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55281/proof-of-non-existence-of-a-certain-metric-on-s2/55371#55371) or [that one?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57691/can-a-vertical-line-be-a-valid-pdf/57703#57703)

Comment: @Michael: If I understand correctly, Phira was talking about [your answers with *negative* total vote count](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/11667/michael-hardy#anpage_11-ansort_votes) where I can see the exact pattern she describes.

Comment: @t.b. You point to two of my answers.  Neither of them was among the ones in which Phira said that that alleged "pattern" holds.  Phira said that among the answers of mine that were downvoted within the past week (there are five of them) that pattern holds.  Nothing similar to that happened with any of them.  The second one that you mention is also not one of those, nor does it fit that pattern.  It still appears to me now that the answer I gave is right.  Yet it is alleged that I said "Yes, it's wrong" and let it stand.   The first one you mention is one where I did acknowledge that I had....

Comment: ....misunderstood the question.  It is clearly not one of the ones in which Phira claims to have seen the pattern.  Among those in which Phira claimed to have seen the pattern, there is not one that matches it.  (There is one among the five where someone found fault with the answer in the comments.)

Comment: @Michael, Mariano has opined that no one is obliged to explain downvotes. Arturo has agreed. Zev has cited official policy agreeing. Phira has agreed. No one has disagreed. I think you have the answer to your question. Time to cut your losses.

Comment: This is a response to the comment below that I "lie and am dishonest" 
when I say that "I had a look at the downvoted answers from the OP and the pattern is".

Even though t.b. explained that I was clearly looking at the OPs answers with total negative vote-count (I will hardly look at every post of the OP to check whether it got a lonely downvote among upvotes) and linked to examples the OP insists that "Phira said that among the answers of mine that were downvoted within the past week (there are five of them) that pattern holds."

Comment: These are the links to the currently downvoted questions one finds easily in Michael Hardy's profile:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57244/counting-the-sum-of-the-digits/57246#57246 (MH: "Oh, I see." let's post stand) 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57691/can-a-vertical-line-be-a-valid-pdf/57703#57703 (MH disagrees with the critique and does not follow up on the question where the critique is mistaken) 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47865/are-angles-ever-multiplied/47879#47879 (downvote explained with no reaction of MH)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55281/proof-of-non-existence-of-a-certain-metric-on-s2/55371#55371 (MH: "You are right." lets post stand)

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52531/laplace-transform-and-differentiation-help/52542#52542 (MH: "Oh, I see". lets post stand.)

I might note that while correctness proves that I did not lie, factual wrongness would not prove that I did.

Comment: @Phira: you stretched the facts to suit the accusation.  First, in several of the instances where you say "the downvotes are explained", no-one wrote anything about downvotes or took credit for such. Second, in several of the cases you raised, either MH's comments went beyond an "I see" and stated the error (in effect making a visible correction in the comments rather than the question), or there was no clear need to correct anything.  You snidely asserted a "pattern" of discounting input in 5 cases, when *per your description* that is false in 3-4 out of those 5 cases.

Comment: Five of my postings got unexplained downvotes in two days; I mentioned that here; then Phira said a certain "pattern" holds among those postings.  The alleged "pattern" occurred in none of them.  Then Phira points to _other_ postings, not among those, where she says the "pattern" holds.  One of them is one where I think I got the answer right, so it doesn't match the pattern.  Another is one where I acknowledged in comments that I had misunderstood the question.  I don't consider posting that statement to amount to "letting the post stand".

Comment: This is a dishonest personal vendetta.  I don't know why it's happening.  Phira is taking advantage of the fact that many people disagree with the opinion I put forth to get sympathy for false accusations.

Comment: If I may revive this discussion (with fervent hope that it won't repeat itself), while I agree with the statement of this answer, it does leave a lot unsaid. It isn't abusive to downvote without comment, and not even to refuse to explain upon request. It is, however, not very productive behavior either, and I firmly believe voters should strive to improve more than they do to critic. Mark an answer as faulty, and you've saved some future surfer some confusion; teach the poster to post better answers/questions, and you've essentially doubled constructive posts in the future.

Comment: I don't agree. It doesn't help the OP to be a better member of this site nor anything. There is always a reason to downvote and if you have nothing to hide then you should say why you did it. A downvote is an action that affects others, people shouldn't be allowed to do actions that affect others without explaining their reasons.

Answer (score 28):

There is a [discussion on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes) about this. While all the answers and comments are interesting, the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes/2373#2373) given by [Jeff Atwood, one of the two creators of the StackExchange network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange_Network#History), says that people do *not* need to explain their downvotes (or at least, not enough so that they face any repercussions from not doing so), but a reminder that one can explain one's downvote with a comment is implemented for users with <2000 rep.

Also, my own opinion is that it is only abusive to serially downvote a single person's posts out of spite, which in any case would automatically create flags, moderators would take care of things, etc. Requiring an explanation via a comment means loss of anonymity of downvotes, which I consider to be extremely important (as did many of the commenters in the discussion linked to above), and perhaps the downvoter has to attend to something else at the moment, or thinks the problem with a post is so blatantly obvious it doesn't need an explanation. If an answer is absolutely abysmal, it's a waste of everyone's time to have to post a comment - it is in the best interests of the site to make sorting the site's content by value as efficient as possible. Requiring an explanation to accompany every downvote would be such a large drain on everyone's time that vastly fewer people would *bother* to downvote, which would thereby harm the site.

Comment: You refer to "Jeff et al."  And say that "official policy" comes from them.  Who and what is "Jeff"?

Comment: @MichaelHardy You *could* go to the stackexchange homepage and click on "about" or you could just infer from context that Jeff et al. are the people who make the official policy in the sense that they decide what is sanctioned by the software.

Comment: @Phira As you can see, I already _did_ infer that "Jeff et al." are people who make official policy, and _that_ is what I asked who and what they are.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: "Jeff" means Jeff Atwood, a stackexchange.com employee. But he does not make official policy here, we make our own official policy as a community run site.

Comment: Sorry for this irrelevant comment, but I just saw the first comment above which I find quite funny: "Who and *what* is "Jeff"?" :)

Comment: "*or at least, not enough so that they face any repercussions from not doing so*" - the explanation could rely on anonymity.

Answer (score 11):

Downvoters do not necessarily see the requests to explain their votes.

Comment: Speaking of downvotes without a stated reason...

Comment: Here's a reason without a vote :)

Comment: I'm trying to understand what a downvote could even *mean* in the case of this answer.  Somebody believes that downvoters always see the requests for explanation?

Comment: Must be! I don't know. Maybe they don't like other things you've said. Again, *I don't know*

Comment: Maybe it should be added as a functionality that you subscribe to comments on stuff you downvote.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with the sentiment that downvoters should ideally explain their votes. My posts haven't been voted down too often, but whenever I see anonymous downvotes, I usually request an explanation *irrespective of the poster*. That said, I agree with Mariano's comment that this shouldn't be an obligation on the voters.

I am also a bit puzzled about the exact suggestion made by the OP.

> Could there at least be some officially promulgated norm about politeness and about respect for the fact that we are here for a common purpose, that says something about this?

What would be the benefits of such a policy (even assuming we all agreed on one)? Whether

- the downvoter forgot to explain the vote and also missed the request for the explanation, or
- the vote is just a hit-and-run case,

I don't think we'll be any more successful in enforcing this official policy, given that the chief issue here is the anonymity of the vote. If all that the downvote victim could do is to post a comment and hope for a response, isn't that what we're doing already?

Comment: I don't think leaving such comments is very likely to be productive -- at least if it's only a single stray downvote. It seems unlikely that somebody who downvoted will come by later to discover that someone left a comment for him to answer.

Comment: @Henning Well, whatever you say does check out with my experience so far: my comments requesting explanation get upvoted frequently, but they do not elicit a response from the original voter. =) And with regards "at least if it's only a single stray downvote", I have a feeling that such a comment deters an unnecessary cascade of downvotes to some extent. Of course, it is hard to confirm this and I could just be deluding myself.

Comment: I do think it would be good for the FAQ to have some gentle suggestion that downvotes should be accompanied by comments when there is a useful comment to be made. Sometimes there is nothing that I can say when I downvote, though, because my limited English skills are insufficient to phrase what I am thinking in a reasonable way.